# Empty list in postman, having data in oracle database, does not show data

Tags: spring, oracle, spring-security, postman

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LJHmK.png)

I'm making a program in spring and with bd oracle, insert data to the db from the import file in spring and insert it, but when wanting to validate the data in postman it shows me an empty list with data in the db

class AuthorizationServerConfig

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class AuthorizationServerConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter{
       
    @Autowired
    private BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;
    
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("authenticationManager")
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
       endpoints.authenticationManager(authenticationManager)
               .tokenStore(tokenStore())
               .accessTokenConverter(accessTokenConverter());
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients.inMemory().withClient("angularapp")
                .secret(passwordEncoder.encode("12345"))
                .scopes("read", "write")
                .authorizedGrantTypes("password","refresh_token")
                .accessTokenValiditySeconds(3600)
                .refreshTokenValiditySeconds(3600);
    } 

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer security) throws Exception {
        security.tokenKeyAccess("permitAll()")
                .checkTokenAccess("isAuthenticated()");
    }
    
    @Bean
    public JwtAccessTokenConverter accessTokenConverter() {
        JwtAccessTokenConverter jwtAccessTokenConverter = new JwtAccessTokenConverter();
        return jwtAccessTokenConverter;
    }
    
    @Bean
    public JwtTokenStore tokenStore() {
        return new JwtTokenStore(accessTokenConverter());
    }
    
    
}
```

class Clase ResourceServerConfig

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
public class ResourceServerConfig extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter{

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET,"/eventos/participantes").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated();
    }
    
    
}
```

class SpringSecurityConfig

```
@Configuration
public class SpringSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{
    
    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService usuarioService;
    
    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder(){
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
    
    @Override
    @Autowired
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
       auth.userDetailsService(this.usuarioService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }
    
    @Bean("authenticationManager")
    @Override
    protected AuthenticationManager authenticationManager() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManager(); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }
    
    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .csrf().disable()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Did you `COMMIT` the data?

Comment: no, I did .....

Comment: I'm not sure whether "no, I did" means you did or did not `COMMIT` the data. If you did not then it will only be visible in the session where the data was inserted and no other session will see it until it is `COMMIT`ted. So you want to make sure you do `COMMIT`.